# How can I learn spells that are not in the druid spell list without multiclassing or taking feats?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid

I am a spore druid, as I saw in my spell circles I can learn some spells that are not in the druid spell list, is there any way my druid can learn more spells outside my class without multiclassing or taking feats?

Also, what are some good spells for druids that do not require concentration? At least 75% of them require concentration (I have level 3 spells right now) and I need some good ranged ones.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. Note that this is a Q&A site unlike discussion forums, and we don't usually do "recommendation" posts. You may want to [edit] this down to your first question (how druids learn non-druid spells without multiclassing or feats), which can be answered here.

Comment: This is a good question, and the answer is (unfortunately) _very_ narrow.

Comment: You're asking two separate questions. If you deleted the second (spell recommendation) question then I'd vote to reopen this question.

Answer (score 5):

Without multiclassing or feats, you are restricted to your own class's spell list.  The Circle of Spores, like all druid circles, gets a list of additional *circle spells* added to the druid spell list for them, but those are the only spells outside the normal druid spell list that you can access without multiclassing or feats.

On the other hand, you can find magical items that allow you to cast additional spells, e.g. a *wand of fireballs*, which any spellcaster can attune to and use to cast *fireball.*  That will use the wand's charges and DC instead of your spell slots and spell DC, however; different items will have different rules on that.

Spell lists are matched to classes specifically to create class flavor and "branding," so to speak, and the druid spell list reflects that -- and doesn't necessarily have the same sort of offensive spells that other classes might have.  *Call lightning*, *ice storm*, and *wall of fire* are all examples of offensive druid spells that can be used at range and have a Dex save instead of a Con save.  (Notably, all of those also do area-of-effect damage.)

Comment: 2 of the 3 mentioned spells require concentration. Flavor <> balance or usability.